# GStreamer When the frame rate is 10/1, the video playback speed gets faster

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I want to save a video using GStreamer in the following environment.

> Hardware: Raspberry pi (BCM 2709 Revision: a 22082)
>
> OS: Raspbian GNU / Linux 9 (stretch)
> Webcam: Logitech HD WEBCAM C270

The video saved with following command, the playback speed becomes too faster than expected.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=YV12,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! filesink location=video.h264
```

However, if I change “framerate” to 30/1, I can watch without problems

I checked the frame rate of the video with following command

```
$ ffmpeg -i video.h 264

Input # 0, h 264, from 'video. H 264':
Duration: N / A, bitrate: N / A
Stream # 0: 0: Video: h 264 (High), yuv 420 p (progressive), 640 x 480 [SAR 1: 1 DAR 4: 3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200 k tbn, 50 tbc
```

The frame rate is 25/1.

I tried specifying the frame rate to hardware with following command.

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d / dev / video0 -p 10

Frame rate set to 10.000 fps
```

But there was no effect.

Also I tried using “videorate” plugin.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videorate ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=YV12,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! filesink location=video.h264
```

But it got worse results.
Even if playback is started, the video will remain stopped, and after a while it will be played at high speed

The version of GStreamer is 1.10.4.
This is the only version available with apt-get.
I tried to compile from source code, but building on Raspbian is not supported and it is very difficult.

**Update:**
I tried Lad's suggetion(Thanks!)

But following error message shown...

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=YV12,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.h264

...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0: Could not multiplex stream.
Additional debug info:
gstqtmux.c(3391): gst_qt_mux_add_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0:
Buffer has no PTS.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing mp4mux element in the pipeline. try the following pipeline :

> $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !
>   video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=YV12,framerate=10/1 !
>   videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! mp4mux !
>   filesink location=video.h264

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I tried your suggestion.
However, I did not get the results I expected......

Comment: what was the behaviour ? could you try out the following pipeline: gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=YV12,framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc !  "video/x-h264,framerate=10" ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.h264

Comment: Thank you a lot. I tried above pipeline, "Internal data stream error." occurred. Is "framerate = 10" a mistake of "10/1"? I changed it to "10/1" and tried it, but "Buffer has no PTS." error happens yet...

Comment: To fix the buffer has no PTS issue, try my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455279/split-mpeg-ts-into-mp4-files-with-gstreamer-1-12-2/49769275#49769275